# Why do memberwise initializers become 'private' when the structure contains a private property?

Tags: ios, swift, access-control, initializer

> The default memberwise initializer for a structure type is considered private if any of the structure’s stored properties are private.

(Source: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/accesscontrol/)

What is the reason as to why the memberwise initializer becomes 'private' when a stored property is 'private'?

And is there a reason why the same does not apply for custom initializers?

Comment: ["Why" is an unclear question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) Please clarify.

Comment: "And is there a reason/cause as to why the same does not apply for custom initializers?" Are you suggesting that all initialisers should be private, once you have one private property?

Comment: Because otherwise the compile would overrule our intention to keep the property private if it synthesized a public member wise init. As for a custom init, well then it is _our_ choice to allow the property to be initialized from outside of our custom type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Because otherwise the compiler would overrule our intention to keep the property private if it synthesized a public member wise init. As for a custom init, well then it is our choice to allow the property to be initialized from outside of our custom type." (@joakimdanielson)

Also from [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/access-level-of-struct-memberwise-initializer/13997):

[image]

[Another (possible) explanation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swiftui/day-11-how-do-memberwise-initializers-work-when-it-comes-to-privately-marked-properties/15195) from Hacking With Swift Forums:

[image]